# Need help with awk syntax errors

Tags: awk

```
config.status: creating Makefile
awk: ./confYwuPmF/subs.awk:2: S["/; s/!.*/"]=LTLIBOBJS!%!_!# ""
awk: ./confYwuPmF/subs.awk:2:                          ^ syntax error
awk: ./confYwuPmF/subs.awk:3: S["/; s/!.*/"]=LTLIBOBJS!%!_!# ""
awk: ./confYwuPmF/subs.awk:3:                              ^ syntax error
awk: ./confYwuPmF/subs.awk:3: S["/; s/!.*/"]=MAKE_MAN!%!_!# ""
awk: ./confYwuPmF/subs.awk:3:                         ^ syntax error
awk: ./confYwuPmF/subs.awk:4: S["/; s/!.*/"]=MAKE_MAN!%!_!# ""
awk: ./confYwuPmF/subs.awk:4:                             ^ syntax error
awk: ./confYwuPmF/subs.awk:5: S["/; s/!.*/"]=BUILD_POPT!$(popt_OBJS)%!_!# "$(popt_OBJS)"
awk: ./confYwuPmF/subs.awk:5:                                           ^ syntax error
awk: ./confYwuPmF/subs.awk:5: S["/; s/!.*/"]=CC_SHOBJ_FLAG!-o $@%!_!# "-o $@"
awk: ./confYwuPmF/subs.awk:5:                                  ^ invalid char '@' in expression
config.status: error: could not create Makefile
```

I'm sorry, this is probably a boring question, but I guess someone who knows awk solves it in 2 minutes.
And I just can't figure it out ...

***edit***

I was able to run this on a different system, ...
So consider the problem as solved

Comment: subs.awk is generated temporary
I need to know the syntax error and try to find the generator function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that it is not `awk` that's the problem, but the program that tries to generate the `awk` script. Since it contains stuff like `S["/; s/!.*"]`, my money is on `sed`.

Do you have (GNU) `sed` installed on the machine?